Error: package or namespace load failed for 'forestmangr'
I'm trying to load any package but I'm getting this error message:
if(!require("forestmangr", quietly = TRUE))
  install.packages("forestmangr")

library(forestmangr)

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘forestmangr’:
.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'magrittr', details: 
call: fun(libname, pkgname)
error: object 'magrittr_init' not found
In addition:
Warning message: package ‘forestmangr’ was built under R version 4.3.3

How do I solve this?"

Reinstall all packages;
Reinstall R and R Studio;


What if you try running install.packages("magrittr") to reinstall the package that seems to be throwing the error.

The error occurs at the same way:
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘magrittr’:
.onLoad falhou em loadNamespace() para 'magrittr', detalhes:
chamada: fun(libname, pkgname)
erro: object 'magrittr_init' not found
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘magrittr’ was built under R version 4.3.3
